# how to circumvent missing record type on insert

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I'd like to make a copy of a row in one table addressed by a field in another table, like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_ins_up_vorb()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
    dienst      dienst%ROWTYPE;
    account     record; 
BEGIN
    -- ...
    EXECUTE format('SELECT * FROM %s WHERE id=$1',dienst.tabelle)
    USING NEW.id INTO account;
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' || dienst.tabelle || 'shadow SELECT ($1).*, now(), $2' USING account, jobid;
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

But this yields:

```
ERROR:  record type has not been registered
CONTEXT:  SQL statement "INSERT INTO accountadshadow SELECT ($1).*, now(), $2"
PL/pgSQL function f_ins_up_vorb() line 30 at EXECUTE statement
```

The tables addressed by `dienst.tabelle` have no common type but the target table (`dienst.tabelle || 'shadow')` is always a superset of the source table. So this should always work (and *does* work in a trigger function, where I use `NEW`, which seems to have a record type).

Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_ins_up_vorb()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
    dienst      dienst%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
    -- ...
    EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO '||dienst.tabelle||'shadow
             SELECT *, now(), $2
             FROM '||dienst.tabelle||' 
             WHERE id=$1'
    USING NEW.id, jobid;
    RETURN NEW;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If you are trying to create some kind of log trigger - read [`this`](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Audit_trigger) page first.